# Sort string from a .txt in a html Table

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my first post on stackoverflow.

I am trying to make a little web application for myself.
This website will be a link list for me, where I can post some interesting links while i am at my workplace.

I have already a HTML file with a form and a table. And I've got a function in php.
This function writes the form input inside of a .txt file. And the input is shown in the table.

Function:

```
if( file_exists('links.txt') ) {
readfile('links.txt');
}
else {
print '<tr><td><p>Your list is empty.</p></td><td><p>---</p></td></tr>';
}
```

Second function:

```
//Get the user's comment.
$url = $_POST['url'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$kategorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
//Append it to the comments file.
$f = fopen('links.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, "<tr><td><a target='_blank' href='$url'>$text</a></td><td>$kategorie</td></tr>");
fclose($f);
header('location:index.php');
```

My problem is, that I don't know how I can sort those post's by their category. I know that in PHP you can sort arrays. But I have no clue how I could implement this to my .txt "database".

Can someone help me with some hints.

Sorry for my bad english, I am from germany.

Thanks,
Nerdkowski

**Edit:**
@Forien

For some reason it does not work for me.

Here is my function.php:

```
//Get the user's comment.
$url = $_POST['url'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$kategorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
//Append it to the comments file.
$f = fopen('links.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, "<tr><td><a target='_blank' href='$url'>$text</a></td><td>$kategorie</td></tr>\n");
fclose($f);
header('location:index.php');

$file = fopen('links.txt', 'a');
$fileArray = array();

// file to array and prepare for sorting
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $pat = '~<td>([^<]*)</td>~Ui';
    if (preg_match($pat,$line,$matches)) {
        $rep = '<td>{{TMP}}</td>';
        $line = $matches[1].preg_replace($pat,$rep,$line);
    }
    $fileArray[] = $line;
}

// do sorting

// revert changes
$fileArrayBack = array();
foreach ($fileArray as $line) {
    $pat = '~^([^<]*)<tr>~Ui';
    if (preg_match($pat,$line,$matches)) {
        $rep = '<tr>';
        $line = preg_replace($pat,$rep,$line);
        $line = str_replace('{{TMP}}',$matches[1],$line);
    }
    $fileArrayBack[] = $line;   
}
$fileArray = $fileArrayBack;
unset($fileArrayBack);

// enjoy sorted table;
```

First my function that saves the form input into the .txt and then your function.

**Edit:**

I have tryed to sort the $fileArray but for some reason it does not work for me.

Here is my code:

```
//Get the user's comment.
$url = $_POST['url'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$kategorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
//Append it to the comments file.
$f = fopen('links.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, "fwrite($f, "<tr><td><a target='_blank' href='$url'>$text</a></td><td>$kategorie</td></tr>\n");\n");
fclose($f);
header('location:index.php');

$file = fopen('links.txt', 'a');
$fileArray = array();

// file to array and prepare for sorting
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $pat = '~<td>([^<]*)</td>~Ui';
    if (preg_match($pat,$line,$matches)) {
        $rep = '<td>{{TMP}}</td>';
        $line = $matches[1].preg_replace($pat,$rep,$line);
    }
    $fileArray[] = $line;
}

// do sorting
$fileArray = array("$line");
sort($fileArray);


// revert changes
$fileArrayBack = array();
foreach ($fileArray as $line) {
    $pat = '~^([^<]*)<tr>~Ui';
    if (preg_match($pat,$line,$matches)) {
        $rep = '<tr>';
        $line = preg_replace($pat,$rep,$line);
        $line = str_replace('{{TMP}}',$matches[1],$line);
    }
    $fileArrayBack[] = $line;   
}
$fileArray = $fileArrayBack;
unset($fileArrayBack);

// enjoy sorted table;
```

When I hit save on my form a blank page appears.

Comment: Is this question still active ?

Comment: No, i solved the whole project with a sql DB.

Answer (score 0):

Just load your file to an array.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$fileArray = explode("\n",$file);
```

alternatively:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
$fileArray = array();
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $fileArray[] = $line;
}
```

both gives you array with file lines. After that you just have to sort arrays :)

**EDIT:**

It's really not nice way to do it. But should work if `$kategorie` is pure text (no html tags) and every line starts with `<tr>` html tag:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
$fileArray = array();

// file to array and prepare for sorting
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $pat = '~<td>([^<]*)</td>~Ui';
    if (preg_match($pat,$line,$matches)) {
        $rep = '<td>{{TMP}}</td>';
        $line = $matches[1].preg_replace($pat,$rep,$line);
    }
    $fileArray[] = $line;
}

// do sorting on $fileArray alphabetically as categories are at beggining of elements

// revert changes
$fileArrayBack = array();
foreach ($fileArray as $line) {
    $pat = '~^([^<]*)<tr>~Ui';
    if (preg_match($pat,$line,$matches)) {
        $rep = '<tr>';
        $line = preg_replace($pat,$rep,$line);
        $line = str_replace('{{TMP}}',$matches[1],$line);
    }
    $fileArrayBack[] = $line;   
}
$fileArray = $fileArrayBack;
unset($fileArrayBack);

// enjoy sorted $fileArray table; to get back to string use $string = implode("\n",$fileArray);
```

Comment: Okay, cool. Thank you Forien.
I can sort something alphabetically, but is it possible to sort something by a category?

Comment: My .txt output looks like this:
<tr><td><a target='_blank' href='www.URL.com'>URL TEXT</a></td><td>CATEGORY</td></tr>
<tr><td><a target='_blank' href='www.URL.com'>URL TEXT</a></td><td>CATEGORY</td></tr>


What I want to say is:
Is it possible to sort all of this entrys by their category?

Comment: Would be a way easier if you used XML database or MySQL. Or if you would use csv file for data and added html tags later. But if `$kategorie` is pure text (no html tags) then check my edited answer. **Should** work

Comment: @Nerdkowski how is it? :)

Comment: Well, you forgot to do sorting. Check [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function.

Comment: @Nerdkowski `$fileArray = array("$line");` is completely useless and meaningless. It overwrites $fileArray with only one line (last one)